# How exactly does Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration dependent on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

Does ASP.NET Core implement `IConfiguration` access to config values?

Most likely my question arose because I don't understand what exactly ASP.NET Core is. Well, I know it's a web framework, Not sure, but looks like it is a namespace in .NET, or a package... I know in php, a framework could be a set of classes (a namespace) or compiled library which is provided as an extension so I presume a similar approach in .NET.

Initially, I didn't intend to wrap my head around ASP.NET Core yet. I needed to store some config for my simple console C# application (VS Code and .NET Core). I've found a lot of topics (for example here: [How to read values from config.json in Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885912/how-to-read-values-from-config-json-in-console-application)) that to read JSON (recommended) config. Given that, I added three necessary nugget packages:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
```

I need to use:

```cs
new ConfigurationBuilder()          
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
```

This returns an object that implements the `IConfigurationRoot`/`IConfiguration` interface. But all the examples are given in an ASP.NET Core context. I have a really simple app and I don't need any of ASP.NET functionality yet.

So I've tried to access `IConfigurationRoot` without ASP.NET. The resulting object stores values from config file, but does not have all methods of its interface to access them.

How to explain this in context of .NET namespaces? Does ASP.NET Core implement methods to access values from `IConfiguration` like `Get<T>()`?

If `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is part of or heavily dependent on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, why is it in different namespace?

If I add ASP.NET Core (NuGet package and namespaces), will it be an overkill?

Maybe I should use soemthing other than `ConfigurationBuilder` to read JSON?

Comment: That's a bit overkill IMO. You could just do `string json = File.ReadAllLines("path"); var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);` using the JSON.NET library (NewtonSoft.Json NuGet)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration), like other packages in the `Microsoft.Extensions` namespace (e.g. [Options](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options), or [DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)), are packages that were created as part of the ASP.NET Core framework. The way ASP.NET Core and all its related packages were built however is in a very modular way, so all the libraries can be used within the ASP.NET Core context, or without.

You have to understand those packages just as libraries. They are included in ASP.NET Core since the framework builds *on top* of them, but if you do not need the ASP.NET Core web framework, you can still use those libraries separately without any mention of ASP.NET Core. That’s actually why they live inside the `Microsoft.Extensions` namespace instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore`: They are completely separate projects. Of course, development of those packages is done by the ASP.NET Core team and the design decisions of ASP.NET Core do affect how those extension packages evolve; but the team is very careful with these packages so that the general use is not affected.

So that all being said, how do you use these packages? Just like any other library, you just add a NuGet reference to it. Since `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is the *base* library which does not come with any facility to load files, you also need [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json) if you want to load JSON files.

But then it’s really straight forward:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
    .Build();

// retrieve configuration values
Console.WriteLine(configuration["foo"]); // bar
Console.WriteLine(configuration["baz:bar"]); // qux
```

For this example, the `config.json` looked like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "bar": "qux"
    }
}
```

So you can just load the configuration like this. Be sure to still check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) though. It may be about the configuration used inside of ASP.NET Core but the underlying concepts still apply (e.g. [how configuration paths look like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#conventions), or [how binding works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-a-class)).

Finally, note that this is really just meant for configuration. Loading data from JSON is just one of many configuration sources you can with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. But regardless of what provider you will use, you will end up with the same configuration format that has the concepts of sections and key paths.

If you came to the package while looking how to parse JSON, then it’s likely that you are looking at the wrong tool. If you want to parse JSON to retrieve a proper data structure, like you would use when using JSON as a way to serialize data, then you should look at something different. The most common solution for parsing JSON (serializing too) is using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which is a very powerful and flexible tool to deal with any kind of JSON data.

Comment: Wow. That's comprehensive (and fast) answer. Thanks a lot. I will probably use Json.NET as I only need to store worksheet names I want to read from excel wb and table caption line number. Still I'll try to get ```Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration``` working for learning purposes.