# How to read array of json objects from configuration in ASP.net Core simple web app using Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-configuration

I am new to .Net and using .Net core to create simple web app. It using Razor pages for views and its static contents for now.

Here is the project structure,

[image]

Now, I am into progress of make this page's content to dynamic based on some JSON configuration. So, I am just adding things to **appsetting.json** file to read the json and pass it to views like below, as per Microsoft's documentation.

following is my appsettings.json, If I change this VideoProperties urls here, it will reflects everywhere throughout the app.

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "MyVars": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "avatar": "abcd",
        "media": "abcd",
        "category": "abcd",
        "subCategory": "abcd",
        "order": 30,
        "slide": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "avatar": "abcd",
        "media": "abcd",
        "category": "abcd",
        "subCategory": "abcd",
        "order": 30,
        "slide": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "avatar": "abcd",
        "media": "abcd",
        "category": "abcd",
        "subCategory": "abcd",
        "order": 30,
        "slide": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "avatar": "abcd",
        "media": "abcd",
        "category": "abcd",
        "subCategory": "abcd",
        "order": 30,
        "slide": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "avatar": "abcd",
        "media": "abcd",
        "category": "abcd",
        "subCategory": "abcd",
        "order": 30,
        "slide": 30
      }
    ],
    "VideoProperties": {
      "EmployeeSpeaksVideoUrl": "abcd1P7vBCYAuFczLD6pojJu0a3xYdbdsDhLj",
      "AppSupportVideoUrl": "abcd1nfi9DvdNOlE2tj2CLUdweIpkT8vyfBnh",
      "ClientSpeaksVideoUrl": "abcd1wvLgpCUJg6cTatI5TjIa-eNBI88JcXlt",
      "CloudVideoUrl": "abcd1ipwoyeGjhq8ouwgfx_NsyS2Xd3ZFCnnK",
      "CovidVideoUrl": "abcd1wvLgpCUJg6cTatI5TjIa-eNBI88JcXlt",
      "FunAtWorkVideoUrl": "abcd14wLg8pM2xNtnd5ZZewism8snlLe9A4Ab",
      "KidsAtWorkVideoUrl": "abcd1PuJVNuaxhfvuG7RMqEwVrzJ1VwsEvjIw",
      "BirthdayVideoUrl": "abcd1JjYoe9TGhWU04qzydyz6OtL2ZT6LS8rB",
      "PongalVideoUrl": "abcd10IKZpaAKCLeiyJ2sTAzdESzzyro0DSGx",
      "WomensDayVideoUrl": "abcd1NLe_TNIin9rcekGUtVEpCpoy_4Cl_SFh",
      "NavratriVideoUrl": "abcd19NyLjLLtPBvz-0iYvMsxt9RQrFko8uSd",
      "ChristmasVideoUrl": "abcd1Siwptmm5r_0p7Y6MR6Y6YbCe_zcJ12fS",
      "AnnualPicnicVideoUrl": "abcd1Dd3atu0vRgGQqVFDJ3ZjiH3YNjdBg_4B",
      "CSRVideoUrl": "abcd1wRmwtnesLkFruwVy-BRjCf-8omWeMtcm",
      "GlanceVideoUrl": "abcd1wvLgpCUJg6cTatI5TjIa-eNBI88JcXlt",
      "HRVideoUrl": "abcd1OA0MyrJz3Ti1HYUH4b3R2Q2yxJsGngig",
      "IntroVideoUrl": "abcd14wLg8pM2xNtnd5ZZewism8snlLe9A4Ab",
      "ITSupportVideoUrl": "abcd1XITYeIFwFaleKiO1Hf3E4u5NnYavSvuz",
      "ProductVideoUrl": "abcd1EgQtDl8nO4xe9ePycMbK42d7Q6pOd_Vi",
      "SecurityVideoUrl": "abcd1XITYeIFwFaleKiO1Hf3E4u5NnYavSvuz",
      "TestingVideoUrl": "abcd12Mx7mJN6tgr7Z80uinPd89BhTuIaZTc7",
      "USVideoUrl": "abcd1wvLgpCUJg6cTatI5TjIa-eNBI88JcXlt"
    }
  }
```

Adding this in Startup.cs file

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<VideoProperties>(Configuration.GetSection("VideoProperties"));
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

In my Index.cshtml, file I am using like

```
@page
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
@inject IOptions<aspnet_core_dotnet_core.Models.VideoProperties> videoUrl
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Mive ";
}


<video width="100%" autoplay muted loop id="my-video" @*style="max-height: 550px;"*@>
    <source src=@videoUrl.Value.IntroVideoUrl type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

This works fine..

I am trying to read an array of json objects (MyVars) in appsettings.json in same way, but I am not getting the values.

My updated configuration in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<VideoProperties>(Configuration.GetSection("VideoProperties"));
        
        services.Configure<List<MyVars>>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MyVars").GetChildren());
        
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

In cshtml my code,

```
@page
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
@inject IOptions<aspnet_core_dotnet_core.Models.VideoProperties> videoUrl
@inject IOptions<List<aspnet_core_dotnet_core.Models.CeiTour>> tours
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Mive ";
}


<video width="100%" autoplay muted loop id="my-video" @*style="max-height: 550px;"*@>
    <source src=@videoUrl.Value.IntroVideoUrl type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<div>
    @foreach (var item in @tours.Value)
    {
        <div>@item.Avatar</div>
    }
</div>
```

My Model for this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace aspnet_core_dotnet_core.Models
{
    public class MyVars
    {        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
        public string Media { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string SubCategory { get; set; }
        public long Order { get; set; }
        public long Slide { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any output for this for loop in .cshtml file. I am not sure what is going wrong here. How to get the array of json objects in Razor pages and also I need to use thois to same page javascript.

Comment: how do you call the appsetting.json file ? i suggest if you can use        string Host = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("parent")["child"].Trim(); in order to access the appsetting.json file .

Comment: And I recommend to refer the URL mention below to get an idea ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156484/how-exactly-does-microsoft-extensions-configuration-dependent-on-asp-net-core ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Change

```
services.Configure<List<MyVars>>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MyVars").GetChildren());
```

to

```
services.Configure<List<MyVars>>(Configuration.GetSection("MyVars"));
```

RazorPage:

```
@page
@inject IOptions<List<MyVars>> l
<div>
    @foreach (var item in l.Value)
    {
        <div>@item.Avatar</div>
    }
</div>
```

result:
[image]