# Convert string to object based on schema

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to understand how converting strings to objects works in C#. So I have the following string:

```
public async Task<String> FunctionReturningReponse() {
     var response = "{'ReponseText': 'Some Text'}";
     return response
}
```

Now I created a schema as following:

```
public class TriggerResponse
{
    public string? ReponseText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Can I somehow use this schema to convert my string above to the object of type TriggerReponse so that I can avoid the error in this code:

```
public class TriggerEmailSendingQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<TriggerEmailSendingQuery, TriggerResponse>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public TriggerEmailSendingQueryHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<TriggerResponse> Handle(TriggerEmailSendingQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IConfigurationSection pcConfig = configuration.GetSection(PolicyCenterClient.PC_CONFIG_SECTION);

            var triggerResponse = await FunctionReturningReponse();

            return triggerResponse;
        }
    }
```

Because when I return triggerResponse which is a string returned from the first function I get this error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Services.Schema.TriggerResponse' [Application]`

Comment: _"I am trying to understand how converting strings to objects works in C#"_ - C# itself does not define any `String`-to-`Object` conversions; that's done by libraries, such as Newtonsoft.Json, System.Text.Json, and particular _providers_ for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, for example - and you haven't told us what library or system you're using to do the conversions but it looks like you're using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Comment: Every `object` has a `ToString` but the base implementation returns the name of the type.

Comment: Yes that is correct I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is not associated with serialization.

Comment: @Jodrell is there a way to create object based on type? Like I am providing this schema type and would create an object based on that, so somethin like `var NewObj<SchemaType> = { a: "1", b: "2"}` ? Somehow this approach so far is not working for me so I a mtrying to figure out how I could deal with objects here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156484/how-exactly-does-microsoft-extensions-configuration-dependent-on-asp-net-core

Comment: To be honest, the library being used here is inconsequential, this is a type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple type mismatch - you declare that you are going to return a TriggerResponse in the `Handle()` task, but attempt to return a string

Why not just update the `FunctionReturningReponse()` to return the proper type? No casts necessary, as to be honest a cast isn't possible here nor is it desirable

```cs
public async Task<TriggerResponse> FunctionReturningReponse() {
    string response = "{'ReponseText': 'Some Text'}";
    return new TriggerResponse { ResponseText = response };
}
```